# How to show your company's and department's name as a caller id in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, voip

I'm trying to integrate Twilio for my company. And it has two departments. I want to make twilio calls as "Company dep1", "Company dep2". How can we do it with twilio.

Comment: I wonder, why would someone give this question a dislike without adding any comment???

Comment: Do you have different numbers for the departments? I brought up the question to 0.

Comment: @CsabaToth We didn't plan to have different numbers but it seems the only way for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are making calls to the US or Canada then you can setup CNAM caller ID so that your business name comes up when making outbound dials. To set this up you need to contact Twilio support, please see [this article for the details on setting up CNAM for your Twilio number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180148-Unable-to-Display-a-Business-Name-or-Custom-Text-as-Caller-ID).

Note that even with CNAM, your Twilio number can only have one name associated with it. If you want more than one name, then you would need more than one number.

If you are not making calls to the US or Canada, then Twilio does not support caller ID names. The only way to get your company name to show up would be for your users to enter the company name and number in their contacts.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. It is a bit harder to understand what is available and what is not from Twilio's docs.

Comment: Does CNAM only apply for calls, or will it show for SMSs as well? We have one number, one name for our business and we sends SMS to our US and & Canadian clients

Comment: CNAM only applies for calls. There was a program a while back using [Google Verified SMS](https://developers.google.com/business-communications/verified-sms) but that doesn't seem available through the console right now. I think the A2P10DLC requirements superseded branded SMS messages.